# Perl Threads Excessive Memory Usage

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory, memory-leaks

I have written a Perl script that runs forever as a daemon process.

```
my $CHILD_THREADS_CNT=5;

my  $q= new Thread::Queue();

sub processJob{
    while (defined(my $taskHandle = $q->dequeue()) ) {
        my $obj=jobProcesser->new();
        my $result=$obj->getOutput(taskHandle);
        #jobProcessor is the large modules that computes/manipulates the job
        //MySql Query to insert '$result' into DB
    }
}

#Daemon subroutine
sub daemon{
    while (1){
        my @new_request=   #'My SQL Queries that returns all  new requests from db'
        for (@new_request){
            $q->enqueue($_);
        }
        sleep 5;
    }
}
#Main thread scans the db, and, enqueue the new job in a queue.
my $scanDB=threads->create(\&daemon);

#children perform processing
my  @child=map threads->create(\&processJob), 1..CHILD_THREADS_CNT;

$scanDB->join;
$q->enqueue(undef) for 1..CHILD_THREADS_CNT;
for (@child){
    $_->join;
}
```

I run this script in unix(Perl v5.8.8) using nohup. 
The script dies after every 4-5 days. No hup does not capture the log that explain the reason for sudden death of script(main process). I anticipated memory leaks, and used  *top -p PID* to analyse the nohup process.

As the script runs continuously and forever, the **VIRT**(Virtual Memory) and  **RES** Memory sizes grow continuously. Reached somewhere around 2GB just in 10 hours.

Essentially, once the  child  thread finises the job(process-Job) ie. `returns $result`, then the memory should have been released to OS.

- Is my thread implementation memory efficient?
- What changes and optimization is required to run the script forever, without outage, or without periodic restart?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I removed the subroutines not defined in the sample and ran the code. I see no leak. The problem is probably somewhere else (also, try a Perl version that's less than 10 years old).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments - there's no obvious leaks here.

You've avoided some of the key 'gotchas' with thread programming by running 'worker' threads from a queue.

I would suggest you need to look at what's happening with your your database calls and your object creating in the `processJob` sub. Common traps in OO is to create a circular reference within an object, so even when the object goes out of scope, the ref count doesn't ever drop to zero.

It might be worth checking if a destructor is called. (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Destructors)

```
DESTROY { 
    my ( $self ) = @_; 
    warn $self . " object destroyed";
}
```